# Positive or negative sign on Fourier transform formula

Tags: fourier-transform

I have seen both the formula of Fourier transform with positive and negative sign on exponential as  $$ X(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$ and $$ X(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)e^{j\omega t}dt$$ I am confused which one is the correct formula. I also solved for Fourier transform by taking the following example $$x(t)=\begin{cases} 1, \hspace{5mm} \text{for} \hspace{2mm} |t|<1 \\0, \hspace{5mm} \text{for} \hspace{2mm} |t|>1  \end{cases}$$ and got the same result as $$ X(\omega)=\begin{cases} 2\frac{\text{sin}\omega}{\omega}, \hspace{5mm} \text{when} \hspace{2mm} \omega \neq 0 \\2, \hspace{13mm} \text{when} \hspace{2mm} \omega = 0\end{cases}$$ Can anyone explain whether both the formula for Fourier transform are correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

The definition with the negative in the exponent is the accepted definition of the Fourier transform... however, this is an arbitrary choice.  It could just as easily be defined with $e^{jw}$ and the inverse transform with $e^{-jw}$.

Comment: in fact, while they **are** negatives of each other, there is no other difference between $-j$ and $+j$.  both have equal claim to being the $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: what will happen if we consider only the positive value of $t$? i.e. to say range of integration is consider from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: What was the historical reason for this arbitrary choice to be the one used in the common definition?